# Issue with Cross-reference and bookmark update based on a VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a excel file with cell that I will update. I also have a word dotx Template from where I added bookmark and cross reference to put the information from the excel file.

In order to input all information from the excel to word template, I wrote down the following Macro :

```
Sub emailcreation(templatePath As String, savename As String)
    Dim EmailSht    As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Set wb_s = ThisWorkbook
    Set EmailSht = wb_s.Worksheets("Email")
    LastRow = EmailSht.Cells(EmailSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'open the template as a new doc
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = TRUE
    'switch for the template to be located on the network
    'Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=templatename, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    'update bookmarks
    Dim m           As Long
    For m = 2 To LastRow
        upbk EmailSht.Cells(m, 1).Value, EmailSht.Cells(m, 2).Value, EmailSht.Cells(m, 3)
    Next
    'wdoc.Fields.Update
    Dim oStory      As Object
    For Each oStory In wdoc.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update        'update fields in all stories
    Next oStory
    'unlink
    Dim fld         As Field
    For Each fld In wdoc.Fields
        fld.Unlink
    Next fld
    'clean
    Dim bmk         As Bookmark
    For Each bmk In wdoc.Bookmarks
        bmk.Delete
    Next bmk
    'save email
    Dim save_path   As String
    save_path = Left(wb_s.FullName, Len(wb_s.FullName) - 5) & "_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmm") & savename & "_email.docx"
    wdoc.SaveAs2 save_path
    wdoc.Activate
    MsgBox "The Template Is ready"
End Sub
```

```
Sub upbk(BookmarkToUpdate As Variant, TextToUse As Variant, TxtType As Variant)
    If BookmarkToUpdate = "" Then GoTo empty_catch
    If TextToUse = "" Then GoTo empty_catch
    On Error GoTo empty_catch
    
    Set bmrange = wdoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range
    If TxtType = "date" Then
    bmrange.Text = Format(TextToUse, "dd mmmm yyyy")
    ElseIf TxtType = "double" Then
    bmrange.Text = Format(TextToUse, "#,##0")
    ElseIf TxtType = "doublebps" Then
    bmrange.Text = Format(TextToUse, "#,##0.00")
    ElseIf TxtType = "dblprc" Then
    bmrange.Text = Format(TextToUse, "0.00%")
    ElseIf TxtType = "integer" Then
    bmrange.Text = Format(TextToUse, "###0")
    Else
    bmrange.Text = TextToUse
    End If
    wdoc.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkToUpdate, bmrange
End Sub
```

I have 2 issues :

- Firstly, the formatting of 2 cross-references change to the initial format of the bookmark when I run the macro.

Before : [image]

After :

[image]

- Secondly, I also have Quick part with cross reference inside, unfortunately these quick parts does not update whenever I run the macr even if I linked them to bookmark at the end of the word :

[image]

Could you help out for the two issues ?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Adrien

I tried to add a new part in my macro to update the cross reference in the quickpart, not working

I also tried to delete and add new cross references for the formatting.

Not working as well

Comment: Please share the code of `Sub upbk`.

Comment: I added i t above

Comment: The eventual format of the cross-reference can depend on how you actually applied the format to the cross-reference. For example, if your document is showing { REF "bookmark name" } and you apply formatting to the { REF } field (and delete the \*Mergeformat option) then display the field result, it will probably show in the format you applied. But then when you update the field code, it will revert. Whereas if you apply the format to the *result* of the field (and remove the \*Mergeformat ), then update the field code, the formatting will probably be retained.